# Defining 2 splits to run a set of steps in parallel

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a job configuration where I load a set of files in parallel, after the set of files is loaded I also want to load another set of files in parallel, but  only after the first set is completely loaded. The 2nd set has referential fields to the first set. I thought I can use a second split but never got it working, in the xsd it seems you can define more than one split and obviously a flow does not help me with my requirement. 
So how do I define 2 sets of parallel flows which run in sequence to each?

```
<job>
  <split>
    <flow>
      <step next="step2"/>
      <step id="step2"/>
    </flow>
    <flow>
      <step ...>
    </flow>
  </split>
 <split ../>
```

Asoub was right, it is simply possible, I did a simple config and it worked. So seems the original issue I got has some other issue which causes problems when defining 2 splits.

Simple config I used:

```
<batch:job id="batchJob" restartable="true">
    <batch:split id="x" next="y">
        <batch:flow>
            <batch:step id="a">
                <batch:tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
                    <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="2"/>
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>
        <batch:flow>
            <batch:step id="b">
                <batch:tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
                    <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="2"/>
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>
    </batch:split>
    <batch:split id="y" next="e">
        <batch:flow>
            <batch:step id="c">
                <batch:tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
                    <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="2"/>
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>
        <batch:flow>
            <batch:step id="d">
                <batch:tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
                    <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="2"/>
                </batch:tasklet>
            </batch:step>
        </batch:flow>
    </batch:split>
    <batch:step id="e">
        <batch:tasklet allow-start-if-complete="true">
            <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="itemWriter" commit-interval="2"/>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>


INFO: Job: [FlowJob: [name=batchJob]] launched with the following parameters: [{random=994444}]
Nov 23, 2016 11:33:24 PM org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler handleStep
INFO: Executing step: [a]
Nov 23, 2016 11:33:24 PM org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler handleStep
INFO: Executing step: [b]
Nov 23, 2016 11:33:24 PM org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler handleStep
INFO: Executing step: [c]
Nov 23, 2016 11:33:24 PM org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler handleStep
INFO: Executing step: [d]
Nov 23, 2016 11:33:24 PM org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler handleStep
INFO: Executing step: [e]
Nov 23, 2016 11:33:25 PM org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher run
INFO: Job: [FlowJob: [name=batchJob]] completed with the following parameters: [{random=994444}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
```

Comment: "So how do I define 2 sets of parallel flows which run in sequence to each" This seems a contradictory to me, you can't load file 2 in sequence and in parrallel, right ? I think I understand what you are trying to do, but I need more details on what you mean by "load": does the whole step1 only loads the file1 ? or do you consider the loading to be only reading the whole file1 first? or maybe processing the whole file1 first ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comments, "So how do I define 2 sets of parallel flows which run in sequence to each?" doesn't make sense per se, you can't start two step in parrallel and sequentially.

Still I think you want to "start loading file2 in step2 when file1 in step1 as finished loading". Which means that loading a file occurs in the middle of a step. I see two way of solving this.

Let's say this is your configuration:

```
<job id="job1">
    <split id="split1" task-executor="taskExecutor" next="step3">
        <flow>
            <step id="step1" parent="s1"/>
        </flow>
        <flow>
            <step id="step2" parent="s2"/>
        </flow>
    </split>
    <step id="step3" parent="s4"/> <!-- not important here -->
</job>

<beans:bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.spr...SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor"/>
```

But this will start both of your step in parrallel immediatly. You need to prevent the start of  step 2. So, you need to use a `Delegate` in your step2's `reader` that will immediatly stop from loading file2, and waits for a signal to start the reading. And somewhere in the code of the step1, where you consider loading to be done, you launch a signal to step2's delegate reader to start loading file2.

The second solution is: you create your own `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` which will start step1 and wait for the signal from step1 to start step2. It's basically the first solution, but you wait for the signal in your custom `Executor` rather than in a `Delegate` reader. (you can copy source code from `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` to get an idea)

This comes at a cost, if the step1 never reaches the part where it signal step2 to start loading, your batch will hang forever. Maybe an exception in loading could cause this. As for signal mechanisms, Java has a lot of way to do this (`wait()` and `notifiy()`, locks, semaphore, non-standard library maybe).

I don't think there is some king of parrallel step trigger in spring batch (but if there is, someone posts it).

---

I've already answered a little while asking to your question, you need 2 splits: the first one loads the set of files A, and second, set of files B.

```
<job id="job1">
    <split id="splitForSet_A" task-executor="taskExecutor" next="splitForSet_B">
        <flow><step id="step1" parent="s1"/></flow>
        <flow><step id="step2" parent="s2"/></flow>
        <flow><step id="step3" parent="s3"/></flow>
    </split>
   <split id="splitForSet_B" task-executor="taskExecutor" next="stepWhatever">
        <flow><step id="step4" parent="s4"/></flow>
        <flow><step id="step5" parent="s5"/></flow>
        <flow><step id="step6" parent="s6"/></flow>
    </split>
    <step id="stepWhatever" parent="sx"/>
</job>
```

Steps 1, 2 and 3 will run in parrallel (and load fileset A), then, once they're all over, the second split (`splitForSet_B`) will start and run steps 4, 5 and 6 in parrallel. A split is basicaly a step that contains steps running in parrallel.

You just need to specify in each steps what file you will be using (so it will be different for steps in first split from steps in second split.

Comment: Of course it makes sense, I have a set A that consists of 3 steps, those run in parallel, I got a set B which should run in parallel but after the set A has been processed. Equal to having 2 splits one being executed after the other one has completed.

Comment: @1174 what do you mean by "a set A that consists of 3 steps" ? You mean that the 3 steps runs in parrallel (let's say `split1`) for a multiple files (the "set A"), then once all the files in set A has been processed (3 steps are over), you do the same thing (the same 3 steps in parrallel) for "set B" (other files) ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. I followed the first advice from Dean to partition the big file, but the initial issue to load the first set in parallel and after that, the second set in parallel too, still don't see how to describe it in the XML or if it is possible. Sorry, no idea how else to describe it.

Comment: I edited. still not sure that's whay you need, and Dean answer seems to be good too. But you might need to understand  underlying concept of  both partitionning and flows to do what you want. From your example in Dean comments, here you'll load every shop first, and once they're finished, you'll load all customer.

Comment: That was what I meant, I tried 2 splits but didn't get it working, mostly due to the following steb not being reachable. I will try again but don't think it works.

Comment: If it doesn't work, try to add the stacktrace to your post (I remember an Exception in the lines of "step x is not reachable" as you said, which shouldn't be too difficult to solve)

Comment: I tried it, same issue, either inner bean issues or unreachable steps. Your example would not be valid, if you try yourself. I cannot paste it here.

Comment: yeah right, I wrote that the next step for splitA is SplitA, should be SplitB (I edited), but the error is rather clear. "Unreachable steps" means a step is never reache by another step, so you jsute have to search which step should be before and check that the "after" is setted with the good one. Apart from this mistake, it works.

Comment: i doubt it, i did set the order correctly, it is obvious that a step cannot reference itself and it would also result in a different error

Answer (score 1):

I'd use two partitioned steps. Each partitioner would be responsible for identifying the files in its respective set for the concurrent child-steps to process

```
<job>
  <step name="loadFirstSet">
    <partition partitioner="firstSetPartitioner">
      <handler task-executor="asyncTaskExecutor" />
      <step name="loadFileFromSetOne>
        <tasklet>
          <chunk reader="someReader" writer="someWriter" commit-interval="#{jobParameters['commit.interval']}" />
        </tasklet>
      </step>
    </partition>
  </step>
  <step name="loadSecondSet">
    <partition partitioner="secondSetPartitioner">
      <handler task-executor="asyncTaskExecutor" />
      <step name="loadFileFromSecondSet>
        <tasklet>
          <chunk reader="someOtherReader" writer="someOtherWriter" commit-interval="#{jobParameters['another.commit.interval']}" />
        </tasklet>
      </step>
    </partition>
  </step>
</job>
```

Comment: I am not looking for partitioning at the moment, I want to run a set of files in parallel, once all are read, I want to load another set in parallel only after first set has read all, for referential integrity, writing to a DB.

Comment: You can run the partitioned sub-steps in parallel with a `AsyncTaskExecutor`. The first partitioned step would be used to load all the `Set 1` files in parallel. Once all those are done, the second partitioned step could load all the `Set 2` files in parallel. This also allows you to easily change the number of files in each set by just altering the set of files sent to each `Partitioner`.

Comment: Thank you for the first advice, I did now partition the big file and it helped a lot. To your last comment, I also did use the async, e.g. I split out the file into n files and read them in parallel. I still don't see how I could bring in order. Say you have customers which bought at a shop, I need to load the shops first to have referential integrity, also some other reference data, let's say products. Those I would like to load in parallel. After all were loaded I load the shops and order data. Besides partitioning, I can't see how to run them in parallel too after the 1st set was loaded.